# Mysql on delete set default

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables in my database with following schema:

```
locations (
location_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
location VARCHAR
)
```

**AND**

```
venues (
venue_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
venue VARCHAR,
venue_location INT FOREIGN KEY locations(location_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

A big problem arouse when I need to delete the location but not the venue. How can I delete only location but not venue with the same `location_id`. What should I do to achieve this requirement.

Example Data:

```
/*locations table and data*/
locations(1, "Kathmandu");
locations(2, "Ilam");
locations(3, "Fikkal");

/*venues table and data*/
venues(1, "Green View Hotel and Lodge", 2);
venues(2, "Hyatt Hotel and Lodge", 1);
venues(3, "Abc Hotel", 3);
```

How can I remove the location "Fikkal" from `locations` without affecting `venues` "Abc Hotel". I know ON DELETE CASCADE is removing the row from venues while I remove the locations of same id. But If I removed ON DELETE CASCADE mysql says FK constraint fails and its obvious also. How would you tackle problem like this.

What I am thinking as a solution is to create a default location in `locations` table like below :

locations(0, "Default Location");

And perform something like `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` but really don't know how.

But I think there is some `professional` and `standard` way to handle this problem. Any Idea Please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can allow null for `venue_location` and on delete set to null. Obviously there can be other solutions as well. But this seems to be simplest in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will probably know how to handle the rest of the functionality if a venue has no location found.

If you want to be able to delete a location with venues connected to it you should simply do this:

```
venues (
    venue_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    venue VARCHAR,
    venue_location INT FOREIGN KEY locations(location_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I mean replace "CASCADE" with "NO ACTION"

Comment: But that will voilate the foreign key reference contrain and thats not good.

Comment: of course it is not good, but this was his request, I said on the top I'm sure he knows how to handle the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose If you want to add location id 1 as default value after deleting the parent record then we have to write default 1

venues (
    venue_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    venue VARCHAR,
    venue_location INT default 1 FOREIGN KEY locations(location_id)
    ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
)